# How to keyframe without ghosting?

Tags: animation

I am a blender newbie, and I am trying to move a still photo of a cloud with transparency across another still of the blue sky. I imported the two stills as plains. I point to frame # 1, add Keyframe with the Locations option.  Then I point to frame # 60, move the cloud, and add another Keyframe with Locations. When I play it, the cloud does move. However, as the clouds move, each frame stays put to create a smeared ghost effect. How do I get rid of that effect?
Thanks!

Comment: That effect would be difficult to create so this is weird. If you switch the display mode to Wireframe does the plane animate cleanly? Are you using the Images-as-Planes add-on? are you using Cycles rendering engine? Have you changed any of the Camera or Render options, Depth-of-Field, motion blur etc? For a test can you start a new Blender file and recreate the issue?

Comment: can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Is it possible that the two planes share the exact same location on their perpendicular axis? You should move the clouds "in front" of the sky at least a tiny little

Comment: Haven't tried to display in Wireframe mode - will try that and post the results.
Yes, I used the Images-as-Planes add-on to imposr the .png files.
I haven't rendered yet;  I just set up a camera perpendicular to the two images-as-planes - "cloud" and "sky", and clicked on the play button.
I haven't changed any Camera or Render options, haven't tried DOF, motion-blur, etc. I will try with a new Blender file, and post a screen shot.

Comment: Yes, I will try and upload screen-shots of what I am seeing.

Comment: I do have the clouds a bit in front of the sky, but I will increase the distance a bit more and retry.